# Resize issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I have a weird resize issue under IE (all versions) in one of my projects.
I'm a newbie so might well be a totally basic mistake.
Check out the site (http://www.sydneyharbourradio.com.au) with IE. As soon as you start moving around with the mouse, the site goes into haywire and starts constantly resizing the layout...

All fine with Safari, Chrome or Firefox.

I have no idea what causes this weird behaviour...

Comment: it seems to be fixed now :) , you can help others by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using the IE Developer tools to diagnose issues with the site. Go to "Tools" then "F12 Developer Tools" and click on the "Console" tab to view issues that are presented on the site.

The first five are:

```
HTML1512: Unmatched end tag. 
www.sydneyharbourradio.com.au, line 109 character 354

HTML1509: Unmatched end tag. 
www.sydneyharbourradio.com.au, line 119 character 33

HTML1509: Unmatched end tag. 
www.sydneyharbourradio.com.au, line 194 character 2377

HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace. 
www.sydneyharbourradio.com.au, line 204 character 33

HTML1409: Invalid attribute name character. Attribute names should not contain ("),('),(<), or (=). 
www.sydneyharbourradio.com.au, line 204 character 33
```

That is 5 of many many many issues that are going on with this site. By cleaning up your code and fixing your code... only then you can start diagnosing layout issues.